# SQL query to get Freinds of Freinds of Freinds (depth 3)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables namely ***t_users***, and ***t_user_freinds***. The Schema is quite simple:

```
--------            --------
|t_users|          | t_users_freinds|
--------            -----------------
| id   |           | id             |
--------           ------------------
| name |           |user_1          |
--------            ----------------
                   | user_2         |
                    ----------------
```

My question is how do I get friends of friends of friends (depth level 3) for a given person with id = 1?

An id is just a number from 1 to x. The user_1 is a friend of user_2. Both user_1 and user_2 exist in the t_user table.

I'm fairly new to SQL.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I tried this

```
select t1.id, t1.name, 
        t2.user_2 as freinds, t3.user_2 as freinds_of_freinds
from t_user t1 
    inner join t_user_friend t2 on t2.user_1 = t1.id 
    inner join t_user_friend t3 on t2.user_1 = t2.user_2 
WHERE t1.id = "1"
```

But it did not work and gives a result of null (no errors though.)

For finding only the friends of a user:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, 
        t2.user_2 as friends
from t_user t1 
    inner join t_user_friend t2 on t2.user_1 = t1.id 
WHERE t1.id = "1"
```

This worked as expected.

Finding Freinds of Freinds of Freinds

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.user_2 as freinds, t3.user_2 as freinds_of_freinds
from t_user t1
inner join t_user_friend t2 on t2.user_1 = t1.id 
inner join t_user_friend t3 on t3.user_1 = t2.user_2
WHERE t1.id = "5"
```

This SQL query seems to work as expected. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hint:  self-join.

Comment: Did you write a query yet to find the Friends? Show us that an it shoudl be a fairly easy addition to get Freinds of Friends

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried this query but it returns null:

select t1.id, t1.name, t2.user_2 as freinds, t3.user_2 as freinds_of_freinds
from t_user t1
inner join t_user_friend t2 on t2.user_1 = t1.id 
inner join t_user_friend t3 on t2.user_1 = t2.user_2
WHERE t1.id = "1"

Comment: Did it not work because you spelt the table names wrong?

Comment: @user2329535 . . . This condition is not correct:  `t2.user_1 = t2.user_2 `.

Comment: aha! thank you! now I understand a little bit about joins. Thanks a ton! @GordonLinoff. and others

Comment: (Btw, it's 'friends')

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query seems work as expected and answers my question:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.user_2 as freinds, t3.user_2 as freinds_of_freinds
from t_user t1
inner join t_user_friend t2 on t2.user_1 = t1.id 
inner join t_user_friend t3 on t3.user_1 = t2.user_2
WHERE t1.id = "5"
```

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your datamodel correctly try below,

```
SELECT users.id,
           users.name,
           frnds.user_2 as friends,
           frndsoffriends.user_2 as friendsoffriends
    FROM t_user_friends frnds,
        t_user_friends frndsoffriends,
        t_users users
     WHERE users.id = 1 
     AND frnds.user_1 = users.id
     AND frnds.user_2 = frndsoffriends.user_1
```

EDIT: With explicit JOIN in the statement if that is your preferred coding style.

```
   select t1.id, t1.name, 
        t2.user_2 as freinds, t3.user_2 as freinds_of_freinds
from t_user t1 
    inner join t_user_friend t2 on t2.user_1 = t1.id 
    inner join t_user_friend t3 on t2.user_2 = t3.user_1 
WHERE t1.id = 1
```

Comment: Using a JOIN would be 100% more reliable and a bit less 1900's

Comment: Thanks!. I am learning SQL slowly, as you and @GordonLinoff have hinted out JOIN, I have tried it a bit after looking at tutorials. I have updated my post with that I have tried.

Comment: Not sure why the answer has been downvoted, please share the details.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Thanks.Over a decade i have been coding on oracle Database and have never used JOIN clause. Have updated the query with JOIN clause.

Comment: In case you were thinking the DV was mine, it was not !

Comment: Nopes @RiggsFolly. I just replied to your comment. My bad, not so used to explicitly mention the JOIN in my queries, i find it easy to read code otherwise and there is no performance benefit either.